# Getting infinite $digest loops due to domain

Tags: angularjs

I have an app that works fine when testing with localhost:3000, but when running on a vagrant setup (myapp.dev) that I was getting infinte $digest loops.  I was able to duplicate this on my local box after changing my hosts file to point myapp.dev to 127.0.0.1 and loading the page with myapp.dev:3000.

So why would angular blow up due the url?

[Stack trace](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24rootScope%3ainfdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20start%20%3D%20performance.now%28%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20ret%20%3D%20thatScope.%24eval%28w%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20end%20%3D%20performance.now%28%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debug.watchPerf%5BwatchStr%5D.time%20%2B%3D%20%28end%20-%20start%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debug.watchPerf%5BwatchStr%5D.calls%20%2B%3D%201%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20ret%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%20newVal%3a%20%5B%5D%3B%20oldVal%3a%20%5B%5D%22%5D,%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20start%20%3D%20performance.now%28%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20ret%20%3D%20thatScope.%24eval%28w%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20end%20%3D%20performance.now%28%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debug.watchPerf%5BwatchStr%5D.time%20%2B%3D%20%28end%20-%20start%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debug.watchPerf%5BwatchStr%5D.calls%20%2B%3D%201%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20ret%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%20newVal%3a%20%5B%5D%3B%20oldVal%3a%20%5B%5D%22%5D,%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20start%20%3D%20performance.now%28%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20ret%20%3D%20thatScope.%24eval%28w%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20end%20%3D%20performance.now%28%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debug.watchPerf%5BwatchStr%5D.time%20%2B%3D%20%28end%20-%20start%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debug.watchPerf%5BwatchStr%5D.calls%20%2B%3D%201%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20ret%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%20newVal%3a%20%5B%5D%3B%20oldVal%3a%20%5B%5D%22%5D,%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20start%20%3D%20performance.now%28%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20ret%20%3D%20thatScope.%24eval%28w%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20end%20%3D%20performance.now%28%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debug.watchPerf%5BwatchStr%5D.time%20%2B%3D%20%28end%20-%20start%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debug.watchPerf%5BwatchStr%5D.calls%20%2B%3D%201%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20ret%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%20newVal%3a%20%5B%5D%3B%20oldVal%3a%20%5B%5D%22%5D,%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20start%20%3D%20performance.now%28%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20ret%20%3D%20thatScope.%24eval%28w%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20end%20%3D%20performance.now%28%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debug.watchPerf%5BwatchStr%5D.time%20%2B%3D%20%28end%20-%20start%29%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debug.watchPerf%5BwatchStr%5D.calls%20%2B%3D%201%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20ret%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%20newVal%3a%20%5B%5D%3B%20oldVal%3a%20%5B%5D%22%5D%5D)

**Update**
The error remains if I clear the cache or do hard reloads, but if I load the page in an incognito tab things work. So maybe this is a weird chrome caching bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try checking each of the data of the responses you get back from the server to confirm they're what you're expecting. Specifically I know I've run into similar infinite digest loop issues in the past when the server returned the index.html file in the response rather than, for example, a different template I was expecting.

For example, let's say I have an index.html file in the root that looks like this:

```
<html>
  <ng-view>
</html>
```

And within my ng-view I request a template (e.g. name.tpl.html) that I think just looks like this:

```
<span>Name: {{name}}</span>
```

If the server returns the index.html file to me by mistake (easy to do with an incorrect server setup when using HTML5 push state), the digest loop error happens because it doesn't handle the infinite loop of nested `ng-view` tags.